# Docker not display my codeigniter app in browser

Tags: docker, codeigniter-3

I am new installing docker in my pc (Windows 10 Home).

I installed docker desktop and also I donwloaded my Codeigniter3 from a git repository.
Inside my webapp directory I executed this command:

```
c:\mywebapp>docker build --tag localhost/recipes .
c:\mywebapp>docker run -h  localhost -p 80 localhost/recipes
```

[image]

Likewise, my codeingiter application/config/config.php has

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/recipes';
```

Also my database config is like this:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'recipes';
```

If I search in my browser for http://localhost/recipes
I receive this error:
[image]

Finally, my Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli


COPY recipes /var/www/html
EXPOSE 8000
```

I need to see though Docker my classic CI3 init page, like this

[image]

At last, before i forget, if I write in my browser http://localhost/ this is redirected to http://localhost/tutorial (Docker's tutorial page)
[image]

Any suggestion or help please? what could be my mistake?
thanks!

Comment: do you have any configs for webserver? can you say that what is the result of docker logs <<container_name>>.
please give us your docker-compose file also

Comment: Yes sir! Finally! I made this example https://medium.com/ibexoft/setup-codeigniter-docker-container-for-development-9f7c6552bdd7

Comment: 1. Downloaded the docker-compose.yml file into my project folder from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-codeigniter/master/docker-compose.yml
2. And from the command prompt I ran the following command (my project folder): docker-compose up -d